# Web music player - how to make scroll bar

Tags: javascript, html

I want ot make something like this:
[image]
So, when I click on part of this line, music in my player will start playing music from chosen moment.
How should I do that (detect where user clicked on this bar)? Use canvas or maybe there is another way?
I think canvas won't be good idea, but what to use instead?

Comment: Hi, what exactly is your question here - how to program the player (which one?), or how to design the widget that will show the user their position? This needs way more detail.

Comment: How to detect in which moment user want to play music. In which place he clicked on this bar.

Comment: Try a normal range input and keep them synced with JS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can try this: 
    http://jqueryui.com/slider/#rangemin

When you move the slider, you can detect that event, and possibly ask you player API to go to that instant.

```
 You can try ans see if it helps.
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WBFa4/97/)

Answer (score 2):

Basic idea:

- Add a `onclick` event handler to your "control" (like a `<span>` or `<div>`).
- Determine the position the user clicked (this can be tricky based on the browsers you'd like to support; [example](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/mouseclickeventcoordinates.htm)).
- Compare the clicked position with the width of your "control" to determine the relative position (e.g. start playing at 50%, 75%, etc.; `relpos = x / width;`).
- Change your playback position based on the determined relative position (`playpos = duration * relpos;`)